# Unable to update state at end of async function

Tags: reactjs

I have an async function that updates a few arrays in `context`. Once the updates are done, I have local state that should change the component from being in an "edit" mode to a "view" mode. My problem is that all of the array updates work, but I get an error when adding the line of code to set the view from edit back to view, I get `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child`.

I tried creating an external async function to change the view state that would be triggered at the end of the rest of the `await` functions, but I receive the same error when doing that.

Here is the relevant code:

```
const [editMode, setEditMode] = useState(false);

async function updateItem(node) {
      //Update main node listing
      let newNodeList = [...nodeData];
      newNodeList[node.itemindex].itemname = node.itemname;
      newNodeList[node.itemindex].itemid = node.itemid;
      newNodeList[node.itemindex].process = node.process;
      if (newNodeList[node.itemindex].process === undefined) {
        newNodeList[node.itemindex].process = {};
        newNodeList[node.itemindex].process.label = "";
      } else {
        newNodeList[node.itemindex].process.label = node.process;
      }

      await setNodeData(newNodeList);

      //Update active node
      await props.setActiveNode(newNodeList[node.itemindex]);
      setEditMode(false);
    }
```

If I comment out the `setEditMode` at the end, then everything else works, but the component doesn't go back into view mode.

Comment: Do those things you're awaiting actually return promises? Because it looks like they don't. It looks like you want the change to happen after the component re-renders, but the hook setters don't return promises to await.

Comment: @JaredSmith you're right. I copied the block of code from another part of my app that makes API calls with the functions. I removed the `awaits` from the code, but still get the same result.

Comment: That error will be from either a render method of a class component or the return value of a function component. You aren't showing either one, so impossible to say.

Comment: @JaredSmith yeah, I just realized it was an issue with what was being returned in the `props.setActiveNode` hook. After I updated it I was able to get it working.